# How to limit a form submission according to database limit

Tags: php, forms, post, limit

I have:

- 1 form on a page visible only to logged in users
- 1 database containing three columns ("username", "password" and "limit")

I want to limit the times an user can submit a form based on the MySQL "limit" value and can't seem to find a solution.

Also the "limit" value should be updated each time an user makes a new form submission.

Any ideas?

Comment: Create a column in your database table that increments every time the user submits a form, and use date and time as well.

Comment: Store the UserID against each form submission in the table, do a `select count` from the table based on the UserID before presenting the form.

Comment: Can you provide more info? Not sure I understand how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You will need another table to store total form submit by each user.

Answer (score 0):

That's not what limit is for. Limit actually limits the number of records returned from a query. You could solve this a number of ways. Perhaps the simplest would be to have a table where each row tracks a form submission by user ID and form name. Once you had received three records for that user and row in the table you could disallow further attempts to submit. Then you could have your "success" event clear the records.

Answer (score 0):

`MySQL Limit` is only used to limit the number of records you retrieve using a select statement on a `View` or a `Table.`

If I say,

```
Select username from user order by userid limit 5, offset 10,
```

What happens here is it displays 5 rows, starting from `10th row` and ending up with the `14th row`.

The `MYSQL Limit` can never be used for any other purpose. So, the idea of using this one to limit form submissions is `just not possible`.

However, you can have a column in the user table in the database called "`user_submissioncount`"
Here you start with a default value of `0`. When the user submits the form, increment it. There's a catch : check for the value of this column before the user submits the form. If it is 1, just throw an error to the user and don't accept the submission.

To make sure only logged in users can submit forms, you can use `$_SESSION`.